# CakePHP with Vendors

Tags: php, composer, cakephp-2

Olá, bom dia.
Eu tenho um projeto feito no CakePHP 2 e, surgiu a necessidade de utilizar o HTML2PDF, instalável pelo Composer, que nunca foi usado nesse projeto.
Quando instalo o HTML2PDF pelo Composer, ele é instalado em /Vendors/, e é criado um arquivo executável autoload do composer.

Como posso utilizar esse autoload do composer dentro do meu projeto? Como devo chamá-lo de dentro do projeto. Obrigado a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Boa tarde, traduza sua pergunta você está no pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: ah sim, rsrs, nunca havia postado nada aqui. Agora entendi. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas o CakePHP já não utiliza o Composer? Como que ele nunca foi utilizado no projeto?